# Rotated text is jumps when I hover cursor over it

Tags: css

I'm feeling puzzled at this phenomenon where my rotated text seems to move position when I hover over it and I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/99o3ru7a/

HTML:

```
<div id= "social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Behance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Loop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--social-->
```

CSS:

```
#social {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin:left; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-transform-origin:left; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin:left;
    position: fixed;
    top:75%;
    left:30px;
    width:100%;
}
#social ul {
    list-style:none;
}
#social a {
    color:#F00;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
#social a:hover {
    border-bottom:3px solid #F00;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/99o3ru7a/1/) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a `padding` and a `border-bottom` to your anchor tag only while doing a hover and this essentially increases the overall height of your element and hence you see a displacement during `hover`.

To fix this, you can add both the `border-bottom` and `padding` to the un-hovered state itself like below:

```
#social a {
    color:#F00;
    margin:0 20px 0 20px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.5em;
    border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

Setting `transparent` as the color for the `border-bottom` would mean that even though the `border-bottom` exists nothing will be seen on screen when the link is not hovered. When you do hover, the color would be changed to `red` but the height it takes will remain the same because even in the un-hovered state it did have a 3px border (that was transparent).

```css
#social {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: left;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75%;
  left: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
#social ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#social a {
  color: #F00;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#social a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #F00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Behance</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The Loop</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--social-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the height of #social:

```
#social {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin:left; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-transform-origin:left; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin:left;
    position: fixed;
    top:75%;
    left:30px;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```